# Celerybeat container dying frequently on container with "corrupted size vs. prev_size"

Tags: python, c, django, kubernetes, celerybeat

I have django app working on pod on Openshift.
I also have a celerybeat working on the same namespace.

My celerybeat is dying many times a day with such issues:

- corrupted size vs. prev_size
- free(): invalid pointer
- malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected

I don't have any C code there and celerybeat doesn't do anything besides creating new tasks on redis.

Do you have any ideas what may be wrong or where to look for the help?
So far I've updated **python** to newer version, insalled **top** linux tool to check the memory usage.
I have no idea what's wrong as the only thing it shows is this C related issue. No python traceback at all.

**Architecture details:**

**Container:** RHEL 8.5 on Openshift 3

**Backend:** Python3.9 + Django 3.2

**Celery:** 5.3.1

**django-celery-beat:** 2.5.0